# Select multiple images and drag to change their order before storing in database in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, file-upload, draggable, multiple-file-upload

I have multiple images for single column.
I want to reorder all images before uploading in database. I want this functionality for featured image.

I have this code

```
{{-- images[] --}}
    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
        <label for="" class="form-label">Images</label>
        @if ($product->images)
        <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control" multiple>
        @else
        <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control" multiple required>
        @endif
        @error('images')
            <div class="error">{{ $message }}</div>
        @enderror
    </div>
```

while upload i want to reorder all selected images.